# Brackets in a Request URL are legal but not in a URI (Java)?

Tags: java, url, servlets, uri

Apparently brackets are not allowed in URI paths.

I'm not sure if this is a Tomcat problem but I'm getting request with paths that contains `]`.

In otherwords

```
request.getRequestURL() == "http://localhost:8080/a]b"
request.getRequestURI() == "/a]b"
```

BTW getRequestURL() and URI are generally escaped ie for `http://localhost:8080/a b`

```
request.getRequestURL() == "http://localhost:8080/a%20b"
```

So if you try to do:

```
new URI("http://localhost:8080/a]b")
new URI(request.getRequestURL())
```

It will fail with a URI parsing exception.
If I escape the path that will make the `%20` double escaped.

**How do I turn Servlet Request URLs into URIs?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java's URI appears to be very strict and requires escaping for the [Excluded US-ASCII Charset](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-2.4.3).

To fix this I encode those and only those characters minus the `'%'` and `'#'` as the URL may already contain those character. I used Http Clients URI utils which for some reason is not in HttpComponents.

```
private static BitSet badUriChars = new BitSet(256);
static {
    badUriChars.set(0, 255, true);
    badUriChars.andNot(org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI.unwise);
    badUriChars.andNot(org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI.space);
    badUriChars.andNot(org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI.control);
    badUriChars.set('<', false);
    badUriChars.set('>', false);
    badUriChars.set('"', false);
}

public static URI toURIorFail(String url) throws URISyntaxException {
    URI uri = URIUtil.encode(url, badUriChars, "UTF-8");
    return new URI(uri);
}
```

Edit: Here are some related SO posts (more to come):

- [Which characters make a URL invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid/1547922#1547922)

Comment: `URI` is not so much as strict as correct. `URL` is somewhat less correct.

Comment: I agree. IMHO it appears `URL` should not really be considered a  true subset of `URI`.

Comment: `java.net.URL` is just broken.

Comment: I don't know/think its java.net.URL's fault for this one (although it is defiantly broken for other things). The reason is almost all user agents (browsers) are happy to send "[" or "]" and will not escape it but if you try to put a space in a URL the user agent will either auto escape it or fail.

Comment: RFC2396 has been obsoleted by RFC3986. Square brackets are now allowed, but only to delimit IPv6 addresses. "A host identified by an Internet Protocol literal address, version 6
   [RFC3513] or later, is distinguished by enclosing the IP literal
   within square brackets ("[" and "]").  This is the only place where
   square bracket characters are allowed in the URI syntax." http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt